# Laravel Route Domain - skip some domain

Tags: php, laravel, routes, dns, middleware

*Hi*

My application has to work with several domains. But I need certain routers to be **ignored by ONE specific domain** (base.domain).

As a result, the routers must work with different domains than the base.domain

Help please, spent a lot of time and could not do it.

```
// this code doesn't need to work with "base.domain"

Route::group(['domain' => '{domain}.{ltd}'], function() {

 //some routes

});
```

if the domain will be "base.domain" - these are the routers you should ignore and use the other ones.

I tried using middleware instead of the Route::domain, but it's fail :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do this via **[middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/middleware)**, create a subdomain middleware for route group and check for base domain in middleware and restrict to proceed further, something like below:

***In your routes/web.php***

```
Route::middleware(['subdomain'])->group(function(){
     //some routes for subdomains only..
});
```

Create a new middleware in your app and define in **$routeMiddleware** under **app/Http/Kernel.php**

***In app/Http/Middleware/Subdomain.php***

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next){
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == config('app.base_domain')){
        // redirect to base domain 
        return redirect(config('app.base_domain'));
        
        //Or your can abort the request 404
        abort(404,'Not Found');

    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Define **base_domain** variable in your **config/app.php**

That's it!